# Find and delete obsolete Laravel localization

Tags: laravel, localization

I have a long-time project in production made with Laravel. It is a multilingual site and I used the standard localization of the framework. The translated texts are many and over time many have become obsolete (they are not used anywhere in the code).

What is the easiest way to find and eliminate them?

I thought of writing a program that looks directly into the code files, but perhaps there is an easier way. I have looked for plug-ins for the most common IDEs, but nothing to do.

Comment: After two years I found a library that solves (more or less) the problem: https://github.com/vemcogroup/laravel-translation :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an ugly way to do it with the help of `PhpStorm`/`Intellij Idea Ultimate`. I will try to explain step by step.

- I assume you use `trans()` helper function for translations
- Navigate to `src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php` and find `trans` function
- By using `cmd` + `b` in mac find the usages of `trans` function in your codebase.
- Click to right top button saying `Open in Find Tool Window`
- If it gives you warning `too many usages`, click `continue`
- In the `Find Tool Window` right click and select `Export to Text File`
- Open the file in sublime or any text editor to format your rows using multi cursor or regular expressions to get only `your-translation-file.your-translation-key` part of the rows from the downloaded file. Now we have all used translations
- You will need to write/find a script that will give you a similar list which will scan the files under `resources/lang/en/` folder and create the same format for reference point.
- By using `redis sets`, or `two datatable tables and some joins` or `an excel sheet with some custom formula` will get the difference of your created ones(second list) from used translations(first list).
- This difference will be your unused translations such as `some-file-name.unued-key`.

I hope there is a better way to do this such as IDE feature, a plugin or a script.

Comment: Ugly, but ingenious :-) It is a valid alternative to writing code that does the whole thing in one go.